Feature plot in Seurat gives the expression of gene of interest split by conditions. How do I get the p-value and statistics for each of the clusters
I am able to view that my gene of interest is different in the various clusters using the Feature plot. I want to use this graph in a poster and want to include the statistics for each of the clusters for my Control and Treatment group. Does anyone have a code they can share or guide me to a code available online.
This is what I tried:
FeaturePlot(objectar,features = "CHDH",split.by = "steatosis_2")

